# Show custom text in number input

Tags: javascript, string, object, key

I have an number input whose value I am trying to set to some custom text. I do not want to use type="text" because I want to allow the user to click the up and down spinner arrows to change the value.

```
<input type="number" id="note0" min="0" max="119" step="1" value="0"/>
```

However, if I try to set its value in JavaScript, no value is displayed at all and I only get the following warning:

> The specified value "CsMin1" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

I am trying to change the value like this:

```
document.getElementById("note"+0).value = "CsMin1";
```

```js
document.getElementById("note"+0).value = "CsMin1";
```

```html
<input id="note0" type="number" min="0" max="119" step="1" value="0">
```

How can I emulate this behavior?

Comment: Your `<input>` has type "number", and "CsMin1" is clearly not a number.

Comment: I'd like to still use it because it has the up and down arrows in the element, but change the value to a string.

Comment: Well browsers are not willing to cooperate with that wish.

Comment: Why do you want to set its value to a non-numeric string?

Comment: Oh okay that's too bad

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie Is there a reason you want to do this?

Comment: hev1, because I would like to use the up and down arrows and display the actual string of the note.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie That's not possible natively, but you _could_ have a text input and make it change its value on arrow key press with JS

Comment: That's cool, but I want the up and down arrow mouse control for now.

Comment: That's possible too

Comment: I'll have to figure something out more customized. Maybe there's a way to get the up and down arrows by themselves, or just make them myself.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie I've provided a possible alternative.

Comment: what is `soundIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the placeholder attribute instead to display your text and use CSS to hide the actual value of the `input`. You can prevent the user from changing the value without the arrows by preventing the keydown, input, and drop events on the input. When the value of the input changes, if it is positive, the up spinner arrow was pressed and if not, the down spinner arrow was pressed; using this information, you can set the placeholder to an appropriate value to suit your needs.

Example:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("note0");
["keydown", "input", "drop"].forEach(ev=>input.addEventListener(ev, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//prevent user changing input value
}));
input.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  if(this.value >= 1){//up arrow pressed
    this.placeholder = "text1";
  } else {//down arrow pressed
    this.placeholder = "text2";
  }
  this.value = "";//reset value to display placeholder
});
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;/*show arrows for webkit browsers*/
}
input[type=number]{
  color: transparent;/*hide input value*/
}
input[type=number]::placeholder {
    color: black;/*change placeholder color*/
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input id="note0" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="1" placeholder="text">
```

More complex example storing custom values in an array:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("note0");
["keydown", "input", "drop"].forEach(ev=>input.addEventListener(ev, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//prevent user changing input value
}));
let idx = 5;
let arr = Array.from({length:11}, (v,i)=>"text"+i);//["text0", "text1", ..., "text10"]
input.placeholder = arr[idx];
input.style.width = input.placeholder.length + 2 + "ch";
input.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  if(this.value >= 1){//up arrow pressed
    if(idx + 1 < arr.length){
      this.placeholder = arr[++idx];
    }
  } else {
    if(idx > 0){
      this.placeholder = arr[--idx];
    }
  }
  this.style.width = this.placeholder.length + 2 + "ch";//make input fit placeholder
  this.value = "";//reset value to display placeholder
});
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;/*show arrows for webkit browsers*/
}
input[type=number]{
  color: transparent;/*hide input value*/
}
input[type=number]::placeholder {
    color: black;/*change placeholder color*/
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input id="note0" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="1">
```